# how to find an html element or group of html elements by id or class in colly?

Tags: go, web-scraping

I am using [colly](http://go-colly.org) for scraping website. in OnHTML callback :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {

    // Instantiate default collector
    c := colly.NewCollector()

    // On every a element which has href attribute call callback
    c.OnHTML("h3", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Text
        // Print link
        fmt.Printf("Link found: %q -> %s\n", e.Text, link)
        // Visit link found on page
        // Only those links are visited which are in AllowedDomains
        c.Visit(e.Request.AbsoluteURL(link))
    })

    // Before making a request print "Visiting ..."
    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())
    })

    // Start scraping on https://hackerspaces.org
    c.Visit("https://bbs.archusers.ir/")
}
```

for example I want to get all  with 'id Name' id or get all  with 'class Name'. How can  I do this ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://benjamincongdon.me/blog/2018/03/01/Scraping-the-Web-in-Golang-with-Colly-and-Goquery/). really great tutorial for the colly framework.

OnHTML is a powerful tool. It can search for CSS selectors (i.e. div.my_fancy_class or #someElementId), and you can attach multiple OnHTML callbacks to your collector to handle different page types.